# How to overwrite an integer in shared-preferences from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, overwrite

I want to make a stepcounter where you can manually change the amount of steps in another activity. How do I change integers stored in a sharedpreferences from another activity? 
The original values are put in the sharedpreferences in the main_activity, than I want to use a edit_activity to manually put in values that overwrite the values in sharedpreferences.

I tried to just overwrite it, by using the same code as in the main_activity put with other values to put in.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("sharedpreft", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        int newyesterday = Integer.parseInt(yesterdayinput.getText().toString());
        editor.putInt("stepsyesterday", newyesterday);
        int newdaybeforeyesterday = Integer.parseInt(daybeforeyesterdayinput.getText().toString());
        editor.putInt("stepsdaybeforeyesterday", newdaybeforeyesterday);
        editor.apply();
```

This code doesn't results in errors but the app crashes when trying to overwrite the values.

I also found another question that was similair, here no editor was used but only .edit and .apply. This however doesn't seem to work with integers.

```
SharedPreferences sharedprefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedprefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int newtoday = Integer.parseInt(todayinput.getText().toString());
        sharedprefs.edit("stepstoday", newtoday).apply();
```

This code results in an error saying that edit() can not be applied to (java.lang.String, Int).

Comment: Post full crash log, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more accurate to say that "the IDE is linting" that *can not be applied...*

```
SharedPreferences sharedprefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int newtoday = Integer.parseInt(todayinput.getText().toString());
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedprefs.edit();
prefEditor.putInt("stepstoday", newtoday).apply();
```

The problem is, **there is no method** `.edit(String, int)`. For accessing the editor you have to do it as in the example above. Get an instance od the shared preference editor and then use the modification methods.